# Value copy function batch processing

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-processing

I'm trying to copy values from one ID to another ID.
The ID and the timestamp are primary keys.

```
String sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Values WHERE ID = @ID";

var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnect);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ID;

using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        time = reader["Time"];
        dt = DateTime.Parse(time.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        value = reader["Value"];
        insertData(IdDestination, dt, value);
    }
}
```

This function is working, but if I have 10.000 table rows, then it's very slow.

I was thinking about using `SqlBulkCopy`, but this doesn't work for me because I need to change the Destination ID. Another problem is that sometimes, the values I want to copy already exist, so I need a rollback or commit. `Update` is also not working  because of losing important data.

Does anyone have an idea about what kind of batch processing would work for me?
I'd like to insert 1000 rows or more at the same time without having to call my insert function a thousand times.

Comment: doesnt make any sense here cause when matched then DO Nothing.... could use the insert statement where not exists...